# Change a specific PdfPCell in itext for java?

Tags: java, itext

I have table in itext.
I need to change a specific cell width in the last row.
Is it possible?

**edit:** colspan does not cover my problem. I need completely different widths in this row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is many ways to change your last row cell width :

A. With colspan, of course you'll need cells to fit with other rows.

Example :

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);

table.addCell("cell A0");
table.addCell("cell A1");
table.addCell("cell A2");
table.addCell("cell B0");
table.addCell("cell B1");
table.addCell("cell B2");

PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
cell.setColspan(2);
cell.addElement(new Phrase("C0 & C1"));

table.addCell(cell);

table.addCell("cell C2");
```

B. Two tables with the same total width, no space between tables.

Example :

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);

PdfPTable table1 = new PdfPTable(3);

table1.setWidthPercentage(100f);
table1.addCell("cell A0");
table1.addCell("cell A1");
table1.addCell("cell A2");

PdfPTable table2 = new PdfPTable(2);

table2.setWidthPercentage(100f);
table2.addCell("cell B0");
table2.addCell("cell B1");

table.addCell(table1);
table.addCell(table2);
```

Comment: thanks. but colspan does not cover my problem, but second solution may be good!

Comment: @MohsenKashi just for the record I've added an example to the second solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can take the approach of bootstrap css grid.

```
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(12);
    //row1
    PdfPCell cell1 = new PdfPCell();
    cell1.setColspan(4);
    cell1.addElement(new Phrase("cell1"));
    table.addCell(cell1);

    PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell();
    cell2.setColspan(4);
    cell2.addElement(new Phrase("cell2"));
    table.addCell(cell2);

    PdfPCell cell3 = new PdfPCell();
    cell3.setColspan(4);
    cell3.addElement(new Phrase("cell3"));
    table.addCell(cell3);
    //row1 ends


    //row2
    PdfPCell cell4 = new PdfPCell();
    cell4.setColspan(8);
    cell4.addElement(new Phrase("cell4"));
    table.addCell(cell4);

    PdfPCell cell5 = new PdfPCell();
    cell5.setColspan(4);
    cell5.addElement(new Phrase("cell5"));
    table.addCell(cell5);
```

Approach 2:- Instead of 12 columns you can take 100 columns and then it will be like managing the width as percentage.